# Docker private container registry on DigitalOcean kubernetes

Tags: docker, kubernetes, digital-ocean, kubernetes-ingress, docker-registry

I am trying to create a Private Container Registry on DigitalOcean Kubernetes. And I want all data to be saved in the DigitalOcean Spaces. I am using this tutorial:
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-private-docker-registry-on-top-of-digitalocean-spaces-and-use-it-with-digitalocean-kubernetes

Things and pod are running well, I am able to push or pull images and I would like to configure basic auth (htpasswd) on top on it, but when I add htpasswd attribute to my chart values file, I am getting error:

`{"level":"fatal","msg":"configuring application: unable to configure authorization (htpasswd): no access controller registered with name: htpasswd","time":"2022-12-14T13:02:23.608Z"}`

My chart_values.yaml file:

```
ingress:
  enabled: true
  hosts:
    - cr.somedomain.com
  annotations:
    cert-manager.io/cluster-issuer: letsencrypt-prod
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-body-size: "30720m"
  args:
    - --set controller.extraArgs.ingress-class=nginx
  tls:
    - secretName: somedomain-cr-prod
      hosts:
        - cr.somedomain.com

storage: s3

secrets:
  htpasswd: |-
    username:someBcryptPassword
  s3:
    accessKey: "someaccesskey"
    secretKey: "someaccesssecret"

s3:
  region: region
  regionEndpoint: region.digitaloceanspaces.com
  secure: true
  bucket: somebucketname

image:
  repository: somerepo
  tag: latest
```

Maybe someone can answer where did I go wrong?

I have tried different formats to enter htpasswd, but it did produce the same error.